# Why can't I call a class's start function from within itself?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I'm totally new to programming with threads, and since the class is using QThreads, I'm wondering why I cannot call a QThread's `start` function from within itself and have its `run` function start executing independently of another thread (the program seems to crash when I do this). Instead, I have to call the start function from wherever the object was declared. Why is this?

Some code:

```
class ClassWithThread : public QThread
{
public:
    ClassWithThread() {}
    someFunction() {start();}
    run()
    {
        //do some stuff here
    }
}
```

That is basically what my class does. When I call `someFunction` the program crashes. If I remove the `start` statement from `someFunction` though, and call `start` from outside the program, then it works fine.

Comment: what kind of function is start ? static or something ? please post more code .

Comment: Are you getting the same result after calling Qthread::start() instead of just start() ?

Comment: @wrongusername What compiler errors are you getting. `someFunction()` and `run()` should be declared with their return types.

Comment: @Vijay: The Q never mentions of any compilation errors OP mentions only about a crash/coredump problem.

Comment: It is hard to understand what's really happening from this pseudocode. Please provide us a real example that can be compiled and tested, including a small main() function that actually creates the object and calls the function. The bug may be very tricky to find so all the details are important.

Comment: From which thread is someFunction() called? "and call start from outside the program" <- outside the program??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QThread` should be derived only if you want to extend thread capability, not to specialize it for your job like this. This [article](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/) would help you to understand the use of `QThread`.

So you must create a QThread and start it from outside and then move an object to it that will do the job. Read this example: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2006/12/04/threading-without-the-headache/

Hope that helps to avoid this kind of problem